# What is the difference between instance.let and instance?.let

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, nullable, let

What is the difference between two line of codes:

1.

```
 viewHolderRef?.get()?.adapterPosition.let {
```

2. 

```
viewHolderRef?.get()?.adapterPosition?.let
```

I know that it can affect on the type of the argument that the lambda expression gets but in difference i mean, is there a situation when in one of the expression the let will run and in the second know (with refer to null issue)

Comment: See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls

Comment: Thanks but why are you sending me a link to a place where there is absolutely no reference to let without a question  mark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`v?.let` means: if `v` is `null`, then just make the entire expression `null` (the `let` method won't even be called because it'll be terminated early), and if it's not `null`, then change the type of the expression to be non-nullable then keep going with the property chain. So, `v?.let` will only call the function if `v` is non-null.

On the contrary, `v.let` will **always** call `let`, regardless if `v` is null or not, so the parameter is nullable (since there's no guarantee it isn't null like with `v?.let`. The difference is best demonstrated with this code:

```kotlin
fun test(v: String?) {
    v.let { it: String? -> println("v.let: $it") }
    v?.let { it: String -> println("v?.let: $it") }
}

fun main () {
    test(null)
    println("----------")
    test("foo")
}
```

[Playground link](https://pl.kotl.in/a7nvJcLD2)

This outputs:

```
v.let: null
----------
v.let: foo
v?.let: foo
```

As you can see, when calling it on a `null` output, only `v.let` runs and prints `null`, whereas on a non-null output, both `let` statements run. You can also see a difference in the types of the parameters: `v.let` takes in a `String?`, whereas `v?.let` takes in a `String`.

Comment: Does a null instance can call to *let* method? isn't it cause to a null pointer exception?

Comment: `let` is implemented for `Any`, which includes nullable types.

Comment: thanks i didn't know that *Nullable* are included in *Any*

Comment: Can you please please tell me if it is a different situation here:
        (holder as ViewHolder)?.leagueNameTextView.text = leagueName

  ..Why does the code compiles without a question mark after the leagueNameTextView

Comment: The `leagueNameTextView` property isn't nullable so it doesn't need a null-safe property access.

Comment: But if the *holder* isn't a *ViewHolder* it will cause to something "like": null.text. Isn't it? becuase all the expression:   *(holder as ViewHolder)?.leagueNameTextView* consider as null and then we have null.text.. Isn't it equivalent to a safe call chain?